# iphone is there a way to store a image in your app to the Images Gallery?

Tags: iphone

I'm putting together a photo gallery program.  I's their a way to store the images in my app to the image gallery??? I'v seen sample code to get images using the uiimagepicker, but nothing for storing them in the photo gallery?

Comment: [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iPad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ALAssetsLibrary` for saving the image to photoLibrary.

```
UIImage *saveImage = //your image;
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[saveImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[saveImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
{  

}];
```

Also you can store image using [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) of UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

As H2CO3 stated in the comments, UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() is what you're looking for.

Below is the most simple use of this method.  You can replace "image" with an image from your photo gallery, any image from your app, etc.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```